# MySQL UPDATE Query PHP doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a column, I got no modification in the column value can you please help me with that?

Code i am trying:-

```
global $wpdb;
$param1 = $_GET['projectID'];
$sql1 = "UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation = nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID = $param1";
$wpdb->query($sql1);
echo $param1;
echo $sql1;
```

this is what i got as error :

```
Erreur de la base de données WordPress : [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1] UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID=

UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID=
```

Comment: Your code is wide open for SQL injection please use prepared statements. What are the errors you get?

Comment: @SuperDJ no errors and no change in the value of the column

Comment: @AlivetoDie no change even with nbrDonation+1 instead of (nbrDonation+1)

Comment: @AlivetoDie data-type is : int and as an example of the value : 594841

Comment: ok change  query like this:- `$sql1="UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID=$param1";` and check worked or not. If not just after this query write `echo $sql1;` and see what query you got printed. Use that query into db directly and see what error you got

Comment: @AlivetoDie that looks like the original SQL, and the quotes around the ID value shouldn't matter, it slows the process down but shouldn't break it.

Comment: **[How to Prevent SQL Injection compromise in MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Comment: [How to output MySQL errors in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227626/how-to-display-mysql-error-in-php)

Comment: what does `var_dump($param1);` tell you?

Comment: @AlivetoDie when i use it directly in the database i got no errors

Comment: @AlivetoDie now when i added the ' around i get UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID=''
for echo $sql1; so i don't get anything from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `$param1` value may be empty, or otherwise invalid.

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]

The `''` implies that the value is empty; so the SQL is doing:

```
UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=(nbrDonation+1) WHERE projectID=''
```

Which is invalid as nothing (`''`) is not an integer value as expected.

## Solution:

You need to force the `$param1`  value to be interger. You can do this by [typecasting in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

so:

```
$param1 = (int)$_GET['projectID']; // forces it to a numeric value, 1 or 0
```

This will then mean the SQL will work correctly:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation = nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID = $param1";
```

You do not need the brackets around the `nbrDonation+1` and you [do not need quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not) around the ID number, because it's numeric.

---

Please also note:

## [How to Prevent SQL Injection compromise in MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: for echo $sql1; i get                                                                            
UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=nbrDonation+1 WHERE projectID=00
so no change in column value

Comment: so your `$param1` is being set as zero; so you're updating a column with id zero which is usually not a column. What should the column id be? You need to check your  `$_GET` value is correct.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_GET);` tell you?

Comment: var_dumps gives me the following line: array(1) { ["projectID"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Ok so your value `$_GET["projectID"]` has not been set. That is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote your projectID

```
$sql1="UPDATE wp_projects SET nbrDonation=(nbrDonation+1) WHERE projectID=$param1";
```

Try now.

Comment: While good practise, this should not break the update SQL or cause the upate not to occur.