# MySQL data not posting from form via ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having issues with my form, it is not posting to MySQL. I am not sure why its not grabbing the data.

Below is my form data with ajax statements:

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Add New Asset</h2>
    <form method="post" class='addasset'>
    <table>
        <tr>
                <th>Internal ID:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="internalid" id="internalid"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
   
     <input type="button" value="Add" id="Add">
     <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='assetlist.php';">
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#Add').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        
        var data = $('.addasset').serialize();
        
        
        var internalid = $("[name='internalid']").val();
                   

if (internalid === "") {$("[name='internalid']").css({"background":"red", "color":"white"});}
  
 else {
    
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                       
         $.ajax ({

            data:data,

            url:'processor-assetnew.php',

            type:'post'

        });
        
      function redirect(){

        window.location.href='assetlist.php';

      }
      setTimeout(redirect,500);
 } 

    });
    });
</script>
```

My processor file is as follows:

```
<?php

require 'wconnectionfile.php';

$internalID = $_POST['internalid'];

if (!empty($internalID)) {


$sql = "INSERT INTO equipmentlist (InternalID)
VALUES ('$internalID'')";   

}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


}


} else {

    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I have a bunch of variables but I shortened it just for testing. All my variables below, but even with just the one form variable and one post variable, it doesn't populate inside MySQL.

The below is just original / informational purposes:

```
$ID = mysql_insert_id();
$internalID = $_POST['internalid'];
$reg_date = $_POST['reg_date'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$make = $_POST['make'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$vin = $_POST['vin'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$location = $_POST['location']
$buassigned = $_POST['buassigned'];
$camera = $_POST['camera'];
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];


// Lookup Next ID

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM equipmentlist ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"; 

      $result = $conn->query($sql);
        
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {           
            
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $ID = $row['ID'] + '1' ;   }}
            


if (!empty($internalID)) {


$sql = "INSERT INTO equipmentlist (Year, Make, Model, VIN, Type, Location, BUAssigned, Camera, Remarks, InternalID. Reg_Date, ID)

            VALUES ('$year','$make','$model','$vin','$type','$location','$buassigned','$camera','$remarks','$internalID','$reg_date' '$ID')";
```

Comment: Double single quote?  '$internalID''

Comment: Enable [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and [MySQL error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227626/how-do-i-display-a-mysql-error-in-php-for-a-long-query-that-depends-on-the-user). Please make sure you have no errors first. If you have any: post the error message.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` should be `$conn->insert_id` I expect. so, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks... please urgently switch to using prepared statements and parameters in order to protect your database. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet below, instead of sending the data and redirecting, I do a console.log for both. The result is

[image]

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#Add').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        
        var data = $('.addasset').serialize();
        
        
        var internalid = $("[name='internalid']").val();
                   

if (internalid === "") {$("[name='internalid']").css({"background":"red", "color":"white"});}
  
 else {
    
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                       
         /*$.ajax ({

            data:data,

            url:'processor-assetnew.php',

            type:'post'

        });*/
        console.log(data);
        
      function redirect(){

        //window.location.href='assetlist.php';
        console.log("redirecting...");

      }
      setTimeout(redirect,500);
 } 

    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <h2>Add New Asset</h2>
    <form method="post" class='addasset'>
    <table>
        <tr>
                <th>Internal ID:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="internalid" id="internalid"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
   
     <input type="button" value="Add" id="Add">
     <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='assetlist.php';">
    </form>
</div>
```

So, your data is grabbed and sent to the server. This means that your issue is on the server-side. You will need to make sure that you are posting at the right place and if so, try running

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

in your dev env to see what the issue is.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know. I also did not notice my double single quote. I am positive the mysql table / location are correct.

Comment: @Chaolis the double-quotes inside your query are making it syntactically incorrect. You need to try running a query directly against your db, without your app until it works. Then try running the exact same query through your app. If it works, then you exclude the possibilities of connection issues and can gradually convert your hard-coded test query into something more tangible.