# How to parse Error Code: 1062 MySQL duplicate error into PHP custom error message?

Tags: php, mysql

When I enter duplicate field I get php error
***Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'someValue' for key 'someField'***

I wonder, how can I modify or parse in Php this error to something like
***The someField you are trying to insert is linked to another user***
`someField` can be different - phone number, bank account, email.
Here is my code that returns error if it exist.

```
if (!$connection->getConnection()->query($sql) ) {
    return $connection->getConnection()->error;
};
```

I found same question, but it is for `Go` language.

Comment: You could try to get the error number like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227643/7867822) and return a custom message based on  that

Comment: This would work if I want to create generic error, for example : **Error, some of the fields are already linked**, but I am wondering how to get from this string, or sql error which field exactly is duplicate?